# Trying to send a 404 response does not trigger IIS 404 page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page (using .NET 4.0 framework) which will only return data under very specific circumstances. The rest of the time I want it to return a 404 error as if the page doesn't exist (there's a whole story and a half behind why).

Towards this end, as an example, I have a `Page_Load` handler that looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains<string>("q"))
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I would have expected this to trigger IIS's 404 page as I don't have any `customError` pages set up.  Instead I get a 404 response and a page with no content.

I have also tried an alternative path by putting the `Response` code above into the `Application_Error` handler in `Global.asax`, and creating a custom exception to throw in the event I need to bomb out of the page, but that results in getting an Unhandled Exception page instead.

Am I just misunderstanding how this is supposed to work, or have I missed a really obvious step here?

**EDIT:**

Just to make it a little more clear -- I know that when IIS sends back a 404 response to a request it also sends back a small amount of HTML content, resulting in a page with content like this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /doesntexist.aspx
```

Comment: Are you sure there even IS a default 404 page? If you do not define one as custom error page, the default behavior IIRC is to return 404 to the client. I may be off, though - been a long time I did any configuratioon on that stuff.

Comment: That wouldn't trigger a 404 page either in IIS. It should instead send a result to the client with the status code 404. I think you have some concepts mixed up here?

Comment: It's entirely possible I have some concepts mixed up.  I know that when Apache returns a 404 error it also returns a simple HTML page with the status code.  It may have been an assumption on my part that IIS also does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that I can't actually achieve this using an ASPX page.  I can, however, do it by using a [HttpHandler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001).  In the handler, if I set `context.Response.StatusCode = 404` then I get the default IIS 404 page as I would expect.

This page does actually exist -- it's a short, informative snippet of HTML that IIS generates as it sends the 404 out so that the end-user doesn't just receive a blank page.